# How to use Cotter as an alternative for Firebase to verify phone?

Tags: android, verify, sms-verification

I want to use Cotter as an alternative for Firebase to verify phone.
I followed the steps on:
[Cotter page: Verifying email and phone number in your mobile app using our Android SDK](https://docs.cotter.app/v/master/verify-email-and-phone-number/android-sdk#steps)

But I get this error when trying to sync the gradle:
Failed to resolve: com.github.cotterapp:android-sdk:0.3.0

Code is:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

//Cotter
implementation 'com.github.cotterapp:android-sdk:0.3.0'
}
```

And I also want to know how to do this:
For step 2 I need to Initialize Cotter with your API_KEY_ID. Using this code:

```
Cotter.init(this.getApplicationContext(), 
         "https://www.cotter.app/api/v0",
         <API_KEY_ID>);
```

Where must I put this code?

Comment: Did you add the maven repository as per https://docs.cotter.app/v/master/verify-email-and-phone-number/android-sdk#step-1-import-cotter-as-a-dependency ?

Comment: thx...msbit. I had the mave repository on in the buildscript instead of allprojects. So place it in allprojects and...voila problem solved.